# apply css style on element when tapped, parent independent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This Meteor code uses static template with dynamic data. The css flexbox column is used to display elements like paragraphs and li.

It should be that when the user click on a paragraph, its background-color changes to lightgray "simulating a selected item from a list", which works but the problem is that it goes back to white when a li is clicked.

Since the click event is handled by the Meteor template event, I have access to `$(event.target)` which when I played with, it would high light the String but not the whole "list like" space around the string which looks bad.

I gave a different tabindex value for each "group" for no avail. How can I get it to work so that the paragraph remains "selected" when I click to select a li? Thanks

```css
.selectable:focus {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.flex-item {
padding: 0.5em 2%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.flex-container {
margin: 1em 0;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
-ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="sub-menu flex-container">
      {{#each subMenuItems}}
        <li class="flex-item sub-menu-item selectable" tabindex="1"><h5>{{this}}</h5></li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

<form class="flex-container">
{{#each dataItems}}
  <p class="selectable" tabindex="0" data-age={{value.[2]}}>
    <b>{{value.[0]}}</b><br/>{{value.[1]}}<br/>{{value.[3]}}
  </p>
 {{/each}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to retain css from the focus state after a user has changed focus to another item.

In order to retain the CSS change, an additional class will have to be added to the selected element.

Consider trying something like this:

The background-color property is added to the selectable element with the class, "active".

```
.selectable.active {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

To add the "active" class to the selected element we need to add some javascript to our .js file.
Note that "yourTemplate" should be replaced the appropriate template being used.

```
Template.yourTemplate.events({
    'click .selectable': function (event) {
        $(event.target).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

This will retain the background-color on the clicked paragraph after the user changes focus.

Comment: The problem with using `$(event.target)` is that it will highlight the target which in the case of the li, that will be the h5 text only. The other point, your first code `.selectable.active`, is this a legal class identifier? or a typo with no space between them?

Comment: The click function will not fire when the li is clicked. Because the li does not have the class 'selectable' as the click function requires. .selectable.active is not a typo. It will apply the properties to any element that have the class "selectable" and "active".

Comment: The other problem this solution will create is that it will not allow for a selection toggle on the same type of elements, so that once a paragraph is selected, it will not allow for "change of mind". li not having a selectable class is an over sight on my part, it actually does so that items form it can be selected as well. I will edit it.

Comment: How about changing the 'click .selectable' to 'click p.selectable'
This will only fire the click function when a paragraph with the class 'selectable' is clicked.